# Pandas Data Reconcilation

Tags: python, pandas

I need to reconcile two separate dataframes.  Each row within the two dataframes has a unique id that I am using to match the two dataframes.  Without using a loop, how can I reconcile one dataframe against another and vice-versa?

I tried merging the two dataframes on an index (unique id) but the problem I run into when I do this is when there are duplicate rows of data.  Is there a way to identify duplicate rows of data and put that data into an array or export it to a CSV?

Your help is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `DataFrame.duplicated` and `DataFrame.drop_duplicates`

Comment: I recently found this function.  However, I don't think it checks duplicates against the index.  Is there any way I can convert the index back into a column of the dataframe?  Thanks.

Comment: Use `DataFrame.reset_index` for that, but do you want to check for duplicated indices or duplicated row values?

Comment: Preferably I would like to check both